# Unbind expand JQuery Mobile Collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I am using a JQuery Mobile Accordion list

I'm listening for an expansion of one of the items using (in my `pageshow` listener)

```
$("#myListSection").bind("expand",function(){})
```

In my app, pages are switched back and forth. I had a problem where multiple "expand" subscriptions would be created so when I would switch to the list again I'd have multiple functions being called when I expanded a section. 
Therefore, I want to use the `unbind` method when leaving the page to destroy the listener.

The problem I'm having is when I unbind the event and then try and rebind.

```
$("#myListSection").unbind("expand")
$("#myListSection").bind("expand")
```

Basically there is now only one expand event being fired (which is good), but the list section doesn't expand... I'm thinking the unbind destroyed more than just my listener.

JS Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/6txWy/1658/

Comment: Sorry this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/6txWy/1660/

Comment: No. I want to be able to add an expand listener, remove the listener, then re attach it later on to the same div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Set the functions you would like to execute as separate functions like this :

```
function expand() {..}
function collapse() {..}
```

Then your event handlers must be like this :

```
$('#my-collaspible').bind({
     'expand': expand,
     'collapse': collapse
});
```

I prefer passing functions like this because it makes my code clean and understandable. **THEN**, let's come to the main part. Instead of just using `unbind` and removing all the functionality associated with the collapsible, use `unbind` with the function you previously bound it to like this :

```
$(this).unbind('expand', expand);
```

where the second `expand` is the anon function you passed. Later, when needed, the `collapsible` could be bound back to `expand()` like this. (again)

```
$(this).bind('expand', expand);
```

(Assuming `this` is the collapsible here)

Demo : <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/6txWy/1661/</kbd>

**Extras - why jQuery deletes all event data associated with collapsible when `unbind` is used** : Collapsibles aren't native are they? They're fabricated by jQM by using a toggleClass, which, is in a function in itself and attached as a `click` event handler. (Not completely how it works but you get the gist) So by just calling `unbind` you're destroying *everything*.

Hope this helps :)

**PS** Please consider using the latest version of jQuery & jQuery mobile. There's a new kid in the block named `on` which is far more better than `bind` in a lot of ways.